# Dropdown menu not overiding divs menu below with Z-Index

Tags: html, css

When I hover over a menu, the menu li beneath is visible. It could be the div, but not sure. When I change to static and relative, they just shift down
Here is my site http://ocart.site/opencart/

```
#menu > ul > li > div {
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can more than z-index value

```
z-index: 9999
```

use try :

```
#menu > ul > li{
  position:relative;
  z-index: 9999
}
```

Comment: No joy with that.

Comment: Adding relative just pushes them down